# populate soap envelope

Tags: java, soap

I have  a soap body which I need to populate  with the correct elements according to this wsdl definition.

```
<wsdl:types>
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://DEA.Web.Service.MasterCalendar.API/">
<s:element name="GetEvents">
 <s:complexType>
  <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="userName" type="s:string"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="password" type="s:string"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="startDate" type="s:dateTime"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="endDate" type="s:dateTime"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="eventName" type="s:string"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="location" type="s:string"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="calendars" type="tns:ArrayOfInt"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="eventTypes" type="tns:ArrayOfInt"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="udqAnswer" type="s:string"/>
  </s:sequence>
 </s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:complexType name="ArrayOfInt">
  <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="int" type="s:int"/>
  </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

the code to populate the element is:

```
SOAPElement username  = bodyElement.addChildElement(sf.createName("userName","SOAP-ENV","http://DEA.Web.Service.MasterCalendar.API/"));
username.addTextNode("username");
SOAPElement password  = bodyElement.addChildElement(sf.createName("password","SOAP-ENV","http://DEA.Web.Service.MasterCalendar.API/"));
password.addTextNode("password");

SOAPElement startdate  = bodyElement.addChildElement(sf.createName("StartDate","SOAP-ENV","http://DEA.Web.Service.MasterCalendar.API/"));
SOAPElement endate  = bodyElement.addChildElement(sf.createName("EndDate","SOAP-ENV","http://DEA.Web.Service.MasterCalendar.API/"));
startdate.addTextNode("2013-02-01");
endate.addTextNode("2013-02-10");
SOAPElement eventName  = bodyElement.addChildElement(sf.createName("EventName","SOAP-ENV","http://DEA.Web.Service.MasterCalendar.API/"));
eventName.addTextNode("rock");
SOAPElement location  = bodyElement.addChildElement(sf.createName("location","SOAP-ENV","http://DEA.Web.Service.MasterCalendar.API/"));
location.addTextNode("The Well");

SOAPElement calendars  = bodyElement.addChildElement(sf.createName("calendars","SOAP-ENV","http://DEA.Web.Service.MasterCalendar.API/"));
SOAPElement calendarId  = calendars.addChildElement(sf.createName("int","SOAP-ENV","http://DEA.Web.Service.MasterCalendar.API/"));
calendarId.addTextNode("47");

SOAPElement eventTypes  = bodyElement.addChildElement(sf.createName("eventTypes","SOAP-ENV","http://DEA.Web.Service.MasterCalendar.API/"));
SOAPElement eventId  = eventTypes.addChildElement(sf.createName("int","SOAP-ENV","http://DEA.Web.Service.MasterCalendar.API/"));
eventId.addTextNode("37");
//SOAPElement eventId2  = eventTypes.addChildElement(sf.createName("int","SOAP-ENV","http://DEA.Web.Service.MasterCalendar.API/"));

SOAPElement udqAnswer  = bodyElement.addChildElement(sf.createName("udqAnswer","SOAP-ENV","http://DEA.Web.Service.MasterCalendar.API/"));
udqAnswer.addTextNode("");
```

The request prior to being sent looks like this:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<env:Header/><env:Body>
<SOAP-ENV:GetEvents xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://DEA.Web.Service.MasterCalendar.API/">
  <SOAP-ENV:userName>username</SOAP-ENV:userName>
  <SOAP-ENV:password>password</SOAP-ENV:password>
  <SOAP-ENV:StartDate>2013-02-01</SOAP-ENV:StartDate>
  <SOAP-ENV:EndDate>2013-02-10</SOAP-ENV:EndDate>
  <SOAP-ENV:EventName>rock</SOAP-ENV:EventName>
  <SOAP-ENV:location>The Well</SOAP-ENV:location>
  <SOAP-ENV:calendars>
     <SOAP-ENV:int>47</SOAP-ENV:int>
  </SOAP-ENV:calendars>
  <SOAP-ENV:eventTypes>
    <SOAP-ENV:int>37</SOAP-ENV:int>
  </SOAP-ENV:eventTypes>
  <SOAP-ENV:udqAnswer/>
  </SOAP-ENV:GetEvents>
 </env:Body></env:Envelope>
```

Unfortuantely the servers response is vague and just says An error occured attempting to execute the command against the database. I can query other calls to the server just not this one, I think it has to do with the udqAnswer being not properly closed?

Bottom line is 
I am lacking experince with to soap to spot where the populating of the element differs from the wsdl definition. Where is it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using SoapUI to just send several xml messages, and see if you can generate message for which you will get correct response.

http://www.soapui.org

Second try removing udqAnswer. I had issues with web services when I was sending empty tag because it was translated as null and there were issues about that :|